# Encrypting the same message using different schemes

Tags: cryptography

$E_1$ and $E_2$ are IND-CPA secure encryption schemes.
$E$ is defined as: 
$k_1,k_2 \leftarrow K_1 \times K_2$ .
$E_{k_1,k_2}(m) \leftarrow E_{1,k_1}(m)||E_{2,k_2}(m)$.

Hope the notations are in an obvious manner.
$\leftarrow$ means randomly choosing an element from the corresponding distribution. || stands for concatenation.

My question is whether the encryption scheme $E$ is IND-CPA secure.

Intuitively, this would be secure. If you can not get any information from either $E_1$ or $E_2$, should you get no information given both. (Of course there is a loophole here: $E_1$ or $E_2$ by itself may not leak information, however the combination of them may give some information away.)

When I tried to prove it I can not reduce the break of  $E$ to either $E_1$ or $E_2$. Neither can I find a counter example.

Comment: Crypto.se may be a better place for this question.

Comment: At least explain your notation in more standard notation. What do the $\leftarrow$ and $||$ mean? Do correlated one-time-pads (e.g. negatives of each other) give a counterexample?

Comment: Thanks for comment. $\leftarrow$ means randomly choose an element from the corresponding distribution. || stands for concatenation. And I have considered correlated one time pad as counterexample. However one time pads are not CPA secure since they are deterministic. With the property of CPA secure, it might be possible to achieve security by concatenation.

Comment: Correlated one time pads require to use the same key. If the one time pads use different keys, they do not constitute a counterexample.